# Can we use librosa load to directly get audio from a youtube link in colab notebook?

Tags: python, audio, google-colaboratory, librosa

I am reading librosa documentation at below link

https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.load.html

But i am unable to find any information about how to extract audio from any youtube link.

Is that possible to directly extract audio from any youtube link in your colab notebook?Without converting into audio and downloading?

Comment: librosa.load refers to a file ... and colab can load a file from youtube, but can be a good task!

Answer (score 0):

You should use youtube-dl or similar to download the audio, and then load it with librosa.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a way to get the audio without downloading. I'm using yt-dlp to get just the audio from a youtube video (mp3 format) and then using it to load into librosa.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33890649)

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the audio from YouTube, and then you can use the *librosa* ... because it loads an audio file as a floating point time series.

```
librosa.load(path, *, sr=22050, mono=True, offset=0.0, duration=None, dtype=<class 'numpy.float32'>, res_type='soxr_hq')
```

...

```
import numpy as np
import librosa
from librosa.display import specshow

window_length = int(0.025 * sampling_rate)
hop_length = int(0.01 * sampling_rate)

spectrogram = np.abs(librosa.stft(audio_signal, hop_length=hop_length, win_length=window_length))

# Plotting the spectrogram:
specshow(librosa.amplitude_to_db(spectrogram, ref=np.max), sr=sampling_rate, hop_length=hop_length, y_axis='linear', x_axis='time')
plt.title('Spectrogram')
plt.colorbar(format='%+2.0f dB')
plt.tight_layout()
```